# Taking a snippet of a photo and comparing the colour?

Tags: android, image, ionic-framework, camera, comparison

So, I wanted to do this in preferably Ionic / Android. I want to take a picture of something using the Camera. On the preview four boxes will appear (as an example) you then take the image and  the colours within the boxes are then compared against say an array I’ve fetched from an API.

Basically in short a way to select colours within a specific area/s defined and compare them against a set of colours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution using Canvas HTML. You can use a click event on the canvas to grab the pixel colour using the getImageData() method. Android also has a canvas (although will attempt it in Ionic before looking at Android)

Comment: Bit of an update, did it via Ionic and CameraPreview, I used the image returned from CameraPreview to  get the data from a certain region.